# SVG geometric zoom issue in IE9+ and webkit (d3.js)

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming, inkscape

I have quite complex SVG created in Inkscape. It has couple layers(groups), `<path>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>` and `<text>` elements inside. I want to add ability of zooming for greater details, so I tried to implement geometric zoom like in this Mike's example: [SVG Geometric Zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999). And it works as expected in Firefox, but in **IE9+** and **webkit** based browsers I can see `transform` attribute changing, but picture stays the same.
Here is code for zoom:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg#svgCanvas");

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 3])
    .on("zoom", zooming);

  svg.call(zoom);

  function zooming() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Any ideas why it can fails?

Comment: What happens if you put the content in a `g` and then apply the transforms to that `g`?

Comment: If I apply transform to some `<g>` inside `<svg>`- it works, but it broke all stuff, because some elements already have transform attr, so rewriting it make chaos. And if I apply transform to `<svg>` itself no rerendering happens (but all fine in Firefox meanwhile).

Comment: musically means adding a new `<g>` that contains all the content.  If you apply the transform to that it should not mess up the transforms of other elements.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same idea yesterday, wrapping all the content in one extra `<g>` element. So all fails because of Inkscape layers, they should be changed to simple `<g>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by Inkscape's layers, so changing them to simple `<g>` elements by deleting `inkscape:groupmode = layer` and other unnecessary attributes fixed all.